# UIScrollView dynamic status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uistatusbar

I have a scroll view with 2 views in it: a UIImagePicker (Snapchat-style camera view), and a UITableView.

The scroll view is inside of a navigation controller that the main viewController pushes to. I want the status bar and everything on it (time, battery, wifi, etc.) to be hidden on the camera view, but when you scroll to the right to the tableView, the status bar contents show back up, whether they do some kind of cool stretch animation as you scroll (would be awesome to figure that out) or any other solution possible.

Hopefully I worded this well enough for you to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution I found (More of a workaround)
declare a boolean called hidden.
Then I overrode these methods:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){
    let xOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;


    if(xOffset > scrollView.contentSize.width/4)
    {
        if hidden == true {
            print("\nShow status bar\n")

            hidden = false
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
                self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
            })
        }
    } else
    {
       print("\nHide Status Bar\n")

        hidden = true
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        })
    }
}

override func preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation() -> UIStatusBarAnimation {
    if hidden == false {
        return UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade
    } else {
        return UIStatusBarAnimation.Slide
    }
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    print("\nstatus Bar Changed to hidden = \(hidden)\n")
    return hidden
}
```

It fades the status bar in once you've at least scrolled half way, and slides the status bar back up once you've gone back half way again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(hidden: Bool, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation)
```

In appropriate timing (which is not recommended because you'll have to set it back to what it was when leaving the view, just so you know)

Or the override method

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    code
}
```

in your controller?

Comment: I've implemented prefersStatusBarHidden in my views, but for some reason it's like its being overridden since the views are in a scroll view, or because they're in the navigation controller. Not sure if the parent scroll view or nav controller are overriding my statusbar settings.

Comment: @EthanSchatzline well, in that case, did you add a new row with the key "View controller-based status bar appearance" to Boolean value "YES"?

Comment: @EthanSchatzline in your Info.plist file

Comment: just did that, but it didn't make a difference.

So View controller-based status bar appearance is set to YES
and
preferesStatusBarHidden returns true inside the cameraView

Comment: @EthanSchatzline lemme build your scenario and get back to you later

Comment: I appreciate it. 

-UIViewController - when button pressed, creates UINavigationController with its root window as self, pushes a UIScrollView that contains 2 views.

-One view I want status bar contents, the other I don't want status bar contents.

Comment: @EthanSchatzline those 2 views in the UIScrollView are horizontally or vertically aligned?

Comment: Horizontally.
and by the way I just got the status bar to hide. But for both. When I initiated the navigationController before pushing to the scrollView, I called the navController preferStatusBarHidden and now its hidden, but for both.

Comment: I tried overriding scrollViewDidScroll and when the xOffset was greater than 0, call   -     
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Slide)
 but it did not appear

Comment: So this worked:

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){
        let xOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
        
        
        if(xOffset > 0)
        {
            if hidden == true {
                print("\nShow status bar\n")
                //self.prefersStatusBarHidden()
                self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
            }
        } else
        {
           print("\nHide Status Bar\n")
            //self.prefersStatusBarHidden()
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }

Comment: I was toggling a boolean and calling prefersStatusBarHidden, but it didnt work. But aparrently just calling setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate toggles it on and off for me. But it would be nice to figure out how to add the animation as it does toggle.

Comment: @EthanSchatzline you're right and this method is usable but less flexible

Comment: @EthanSchatzline to solve the animation when toggling, you'll simply have to override another method - func preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation() -> UIStatusBarAnimation { return .Slide }

Comment: I've overridden that method and set it to the Slide, but it does not animate.
If the xOffset is 0, the bar is hidden, and if its greater than 0, (moving to the other screen) I call needStatusBarAppearanceUpdate(). But it does not animate, it just goes from 0% to 100% opacity once I move past 0 xOffset

Comment: @EthanSchatzline just tried it out, guess it just jumps directly to the show state.

Comment: Basically I want it to interpolate linearly the alpha/opacity of the status bar as you scroll between view1 and view2. But I can't figure it out. The Alien Blue app (reddit) does it as you scroll down. Snapchat does it as you scroll up.

Comment: Posting a solution that I just figured out form messing around with it. It works perfectly as I need it to.

Comment: @EthanSchatzline awesome! Well done usingUIViewAnimation.

Comment: Yeah, since it happens once you're past half way, it almost looks perfect like its interpolating. Still wish I could animate, not by duration, but by like a "goal" or something animate between two things. But it works. Thanks for the help, I am glad that I figured it out. It looks fresh.